# HTML: "undefined" result when I'm trying to display an hex value of the javascript ECDSA signature in textbox

Tags: javascript, html, hex

I'm trying to design GUI for javascript ECDSA algorithm by using html to display the signature value by pressing button. Unfortunately, the value that showed in the textbox was "undefined" the code as follows:

```
const sig = Secp256k1.ecsign(priv, digest);
function sign() {
  var txtOut = document.getElementById("txtOut");
  txtOut = sig;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" Value="click me" onclick="sign()" />
<input type="text" id="txtOut" />
```

Please, excuse my english. I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Replace `txtOut = sig;` with `txtOut.value = sig;`.

Comment: No need to close `input` with `/>`, use: `<input ......>`.

Comment: There is a tag for button: `<button ....>text</button>`.

Comment: I don't know what `Secp256k1.ecsign` is, but, consider moving it into the `sign` function, say: `function sign() {
  var txtOut = document.getElementById("txtOut");
  txtOut.value = Secp256k1.ecsign(priv, digest);
}`, or, more consice:
`function sign() {
  document.getElementById("txtOut").value = Secp256k1.ecsign(priv, digest);
}`, or, straight in the button:
`<button onclick="document.getElementById('txtOut').value = Secp256k1.ecsign(priv, digest)">click me</button>`.
Notice change of double-quotes to single.

Answer (score 0):

This is a much better semantic with executable DEMO.

I recreated `Secp256k1`, `priv` and `digest` with dumb values.

I also:

- didn't mapped the JS using the HTML mapping, instead I have used the `Element.addEventListener` method to bind the event, which will permit less coupling between code and UI.
- `submit` the `<form />` so I can catch the whole `form` from the `event`.
- remove `id` usage so it can interact with any DOM content and be included anywhere.
- Used the `<button>` tag.

```js
const Secp256k1 = { ecsign: (p, d) => p + d }


const priv = 'XYZ';
const digest = '123';

const sig = Secp256k1.ecsign(priv, digest);

function sign(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.target.result.value = sig;
}

function bindEvents() {
  document.querySelector('form[name="sign"]').addEventListener('submit', sign, true);
}

window.onload = bindEvents;
```

```html
<form name="sign">
  <button>Click me</button>
  <input type="text" name="result" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In line with my comments, this might be what you are looking for:

```js
// Mimicking function
function Secp256k1_ecsign(priv, digest) {
  return "some signature";
}

function sign() {
  document.getElementById("txtOut").value = Secp256k1_ecsign("some priv value", "some digest value");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sign()">click me</button>
<input id="txtOut">
```